# Error Creating Order using Rest API

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

I've been trying to create an **`Order`** by **`Rest API`** and, then shows up the below error

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setEmailSent() on null in.
```

```
public function metodoHudson(OutputInterface $output, $orderData)
{
    $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();

    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']); // load customet by email address 263135

    if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
        //If not avilable then create this customer
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
        ->setStore($store)
        ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
        ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
        ->setEmail($orderData['email'])
        ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
        $customer->save();
    }

    $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
    $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote

    // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly
    $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
    $quote->setCurrency();
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

    //add items in quote
    foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
        $product=$this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
        $product->setPrice($item['price']);
        $quote->addProduct(
            $product,
            intval($item['qty'])
        );
    }

    //Set Address to quote
    $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

    // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method

    $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
    ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
    $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
    $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

    // Set Sales Order Payment
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

    // Collect Totals & Save Quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    // Create Order From Quote
    $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

    $order->setEmailSent(0);
    $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();

    if($order->getEntityId()){
        $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
    }else{
        $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
    }

    return $result;
    
}
```